# How to change the value in a scope in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to change the value of my scope in Angular.js when I'm changing to another view. I have a list, and when you click on one of the elements a new view will appear with different values depending on the list element you clicked. However, the scope values does not change. I have tried a million different things, but I can't figure it out. Please help!

The user should click on checkValues2 in the HTML view1, and then be forwarded to the HTML view2 where a list will appear with the values in the scope.

HTML view1

```
<div ng-controller="IndexController">
   <div class="list">
     <div class="item item-divider">
      Hode og Hals
     </div>

     <a class="item" href="#" ng-click="checkValues2()">
      Ører
     </a>     
     <a class="item" href="#">
     Nese
     </a>     
    </div>
```

HTML2

```
<html ng-app="legeApp">
<head>
  <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="IndexController">
  <ul class="list" >
    <li ng-repeat="test in test" class="item item-checkbox checkbox-assertive">
     <label class="checkbox">
       <input type="checkbox" ng-model="test.checked">
     </label >
      {{test.value}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
angular
  .module('legeApp')
  .controller('IndexController', function($scope, supersonic, $filter) {  

$scope.checkValues2 = function () {
          $scope.test = [
            {'value': 'value1',
             'checked': false},
            {'value': 'value2',
             'checked': false},
            {'value': 'value3',
             'checked': false}
            ];

        var view = new supersonic.ui.View("legeApp#helsePlager");

        var customAnimation = supersonic.ui.animate("flipHorizontalFromLeft");
        supersonic.ui.layers.push(view, { animation: customAnimation });
        $scope.apply();

    };
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is maybe what you are looking for, click the button and you fill the array and angular automatically applies it: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jcd5yooo/1)

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="IndexController">
        <ul class="list">
            <li ng-repeat="item in test" class="item item-checkbox checkbox-assertive">
                <label class="checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.checked" />
                </label>{{item.value}}</li>
        </ul>
        <button ng-click="addvalues()">add</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('IndexController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.test = [];
    $scope.addvalues = function () {
        $scope.test = [{
            'value': 'value1',
                'checked': true
        }, {
            'value': 'value2',
                'checked': false
        }, {
            'value': 'value3',
                'checked': false
        }];


    };

});
```

Comment: I'm able to do that if I'm in that view, but if I'm changing from view1 to view2 the list will be empty. This is what I want. If I click on one list element, then a new view should appear with new scope values. It looks like the scope values is only set if I call a method after I have change the view, and not before

Answer (score 0):

You could do that with ng-router. If you pass the route parameter to the view then you can show a list depending on this parameter.

So you'll have one view that is displaying your list for the link you've clicked.

See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2c3bav39/) and the demo below. (Sorry, the demo is not working here. Don't know why.)

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/view/:listId', {
        template: '<div>' +
            '<p ng-if="dataList.length==1">{{dataList[0]}}</p>' +
            '<ul ng-if="dataList.length>1">' +
            '<li ng-repeat="item in dataList">' +
            '<a href="/#/view/{{item}}">{{item}}</a></li></ul></div>',
        controller: 'ViewCtrl',

    }).
    otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/view/main'
    });

    // configure html5 to get links working on jsfiddle
    //$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});

app.controller('ViewCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', function ($scope, $routeParams) {
    console.log($routeParams);

    var list = {
        // list for main
        'main': ['test1', 'test2', 'test3'],

        // lists for view1
        'test1': ['T1 1st', 'T1 2nd', 'T1 3rd'],
        'test2': ['T2 1st', 'T2 2nd', 'T2 3rd'],
        'test3': ['T3 1st', 'T3 2nd', 'T3 3rd'],

        // lists for view2
        'T1 1st': ['T1 1st result'],
        'T2 1st': ['T2 1st result'],
        'T3 1st': ['T3 1st result'],

        'T1 2nd': ['T1 2nd result'],
        'T2 2nd': ['T2 2nd result'],
        'T3 2nd': ['T3 2nd result'],

        'T1 3rd': ['T1 3rd result'],
        'T2 3rd': ['T2 3rd result'],
        'T3 3rd': ['T3 3rd result']
    };

    $scope.dataList = list[$routeParams.listId];
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.10/angular.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.10/angular-route.js"></script>

<div> <a href="#/">home</a>

    <!--<a href="/#/view1">view1</a>
    <a href="/#/view2">view2</a>-->
    <div ng-view=""></div>
</div>
```